# Gorm AutoMigrate table already exists but still tries to create it

Tags: go, google-cloud-sql, go-gorm

So I'm using gorm in my go app on GCP. I have a connection to a Postgres cloud SQL database. I have the following code.

```
func CreateDBConnection(cfg *config.Config) (*gorm.DB, error) {
    // Build the connection string
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s sslmode=disable",
        cfg.DatabaseHost, cfg.DatabaseUser, cfg.DatabaseName, cfg.DatabasePassword)
    // Open a database connection
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        DriverName: "cloudsqlpostgres",
        DSN:        dsn,
    }))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    // Migrate the schema
    err = db.AutoMigrate(&model.User{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    err = db.AutoMigrate(&model.ExerciseEvent{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    err = db.AutoMigrate(&model.HeartRecord{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return db, nil
}
```

This exact code block (except for the specific models) works in another go app. However when I run this service I get the following in the logs

```
> [user-service-74b59f7fff-zdsfx user-service-container] 2023/08/09 15:13:46 refreshing ephemeral certificate for instance mynormative-grpc-dev:northamerica-northeast2:user-service-dev
      > [user-service-74b59f7fff-zdsfx user-service-container] 2023/08/09 15:13:47 Generated RSA key in 193.751709ms
      > [user-service-74b59f7fff-zdsfx user-service-container] 2023/08/09 15:13:47 Scheduling refresh of ephemeral certificate in 55m0s
      > [user-service-74b59f7fff-zdsfx user-service-container] 2023/08/09 15:13:47 pq: relation "users" already exists
      > [user-service-74b59f7fff-zdsfx user-service-container] 
      > [user-service-74b59f7fff-zdsfx user-service-container] 2023/08/09 15:13:47 /user-service/internal/repository/cloud_storage.go:28 pq: relation "users" already exists
      > [user-service-74b59f7fff-zdsfx user-service-container] [15.230ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE "users" [COLUMNS.....]
```

user struct:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id              string
    Name            string
    Email           string
    Sex             string
    BirthDate       Timestamp
    Country         string
    EthnicitiesList pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:text[]"`
    Lifestage       string
    IsMenstruating  bool
    CycleDuration   int64
    IsCycleVariable bool
    PeriodDuration  int64
    LastPeriodDate  Timestamp
}
```

The service then shuts down. I'm using cloud code to run the env locally. The models have `gorm.Model` in their structs, I'm not sure what else could be given that this works elsewhere.

Comment: Could you add the definition of your `User` struct to the question, please?